# Is there a cocoa framework for image scanning?

Tags: cocoa, image, macos, api, scanning

What options do I have for an image scanning framework on Mac OS X?  I'm not looking for an OCR library.  Just something that will do the actual scanning and importing to PDF or comparable format.

Comment: Dynamic Web TWAIN is about to release a TWAIN plugin for Mac browsers. http://www.dynamsoft.com/Products/Dynamic-Mac-TWAIN.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Snow Leopard and later, [Image Kit](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/ImageKitReferenceCollection/) includes classes for scanning and importing from cameras. There's also a lower-level framework, ImageCaptureCore. Both frameworks are documented in the [Image Capture Applications Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ImageCaptureServicesProgrammingGuide/) in Apple's Documentation Archive.

On Leopard, you'll have to use [Image Capture](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/ImageCaptureServicesRef/ICAApplication_h/), the less-documented, less-modern, less-reliable API. (This stands in contrast to the Image Capture *application*, which has always been great.) I hope you can require Snow Leopard.

Comment: As usual, Apple has broken all of its documentation links. [Here's the guide.](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ImageCaptureServicesProgrammingGuide/01Introduction/01Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005196)

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is old but it is still very hard to find any good information about this topic on the web. Long story short .. I made a bundle (including multiple selection support) for it. Check it out (open source) on Github: https://github.com/ckteebe/SPScannerCaptureWindow

Answer (score -1):

Not a framework per se but the Apple-supplied `Image Capture.app`, in `/Applications` in recent releases of OS X, supports various popular scanners and will scan to various image file formats or PDFs.